# Debugging Windows Authentication in .Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I have a .Net Core 3.1 MVC application that uses Windows Authentication. I am using Visual Studio 2019 for IDE. I use the Identity.Name to get the users login and check it against a database for authorization. I also use DirectoryServices to get some of the other Active Directory attributes for authorization purposes.

I occasionally run into an authorization issues that I need to debug. I find it very difficult to debug these issues as I can't easily alter the user I am current logged in as. I'd also like the ability to Test my application as different AD users.

Is there any way in VS 2019 to prompt user login when debugging? or is there a simple way to inject an identity for testing purposes?

Comment: if you test using Firefox, for example, it doesn't automatically authenticate, instead it prompts for credentials. So you can provide the credentials of a different windows user. Chrome, depending on configuration, may also do this.

Comment: Thank you. Firefox does work! I couldn't get Chrome/IE to work despite changing the settings to prompt authentication but firefox will do. This of course doesn't allow me to impersonate my AD users but I can at least use test accounts with cloned permissions.

Comment: That's the correct way to test anyway. Impersonating other users isn't usually within most organisation's guidance on acceptable usage! Plus with test accounts, you can be more sure that settings etc haven't changed due to other factors.